# How to get Pages to automatically save documents as .docx files

Tags: ms-office, pages, documentation

Is there a way to get Pages to automatically save documents as .docx (Word) files? How do you do it? I'm wondering because I do not have access to Microsoft Word and this is the preferred format for what I'm doing

Answer (score 7):

Pages does not support saving as a Word .doc or .docx file.  Your only option is to Export your document to that format, which obviously isn't nearly as easy as simply hitting the Save button.

It's important to note that Pages support of .doc/.docx isn't perfect.  If the document has a lot of formatting or review comments, there's a pretty good chance of lost formatting or comments when you export your document.

A free alternative to purchasing Office:Mac is to use [Office Online](https://www.office.com), which will happily run in Safari or Chrome on your Mac.  If this is a short-term need, you can download a free trial of Office:Mac.  If you have an iPad, there's a free version of [Word](https://products.office.com/en-US/mobile/office-ipad) for it too.  I realize that none of these are what you've asked about; I provide them in case an alternative to using Pages will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

My answer may be not very helpful but I think there may be some script that after one click may convert the .pages file into doc or docx file, outside of the pages. Apple is trying to stick to it's own invented format, due to compatibility between Mac OS and iOS, so it is very unlikely that you would ever be able to do that. 
Check this one out. I hope it helps:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5539968?tstart=0